# Retrieve a text with certain class name from PHP url

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

How can I get a text property from another page that has certain class name with PHP?
I have an array list of URLs like this

```
$url_array = array(
    'https://www.example.com/item/32',
    'https://www.example.com/item/33',
    'https://www.example.com/item/34'
);
```

This is really difficult to explain, so I made a not-so beautiful sketch of
the process:

[image: PHP process]

The first list of the bubbles are the $url_array's items, which each contains a different URL.

Now I need a method to read the URL, and get its content.
The PHP will return a `div` element that has an `<a>` -element with `href` url, but the url is different for each time.

Now I want to get a content from the `<a>` elements url. It should return a `<span>` or `<p>` tags text content, with `text-class` as its own class.

How could I achieve this approach into a PHP code?
I have tried this but it ain't working:

```
$htmlAsString = "index.php";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlAsString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query('//a[@class="class-name"]/@href');
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodeList->length; $i++) {
    $url_price = $nodeList->item($i)->value . "<br/>\n";
    $retrieve_text_begin = explode('<div class="text-property">', 
    $url_price);
    $retrieve_text_end = explode('</div>', $retrieve_text_begin[1]);
    echo $retrieve_text_end[0];
}
```

I know that the `$htmlAsString = "index.php";` might be the problem.

Comment: Did you try `$htmlAsString = file_get_contents($url);`?

Comment: It is not working, for somehow it's returning a parsing error and UTF-8 related errors. I found another (much more simplier) solution for this, but it would be still interesting to know how to solve this problem. Might need this later

Comment: Maybe have a look to `DOMDocument`'s [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php). You could specify the `$encoding`.